# Connection leak warning from HttpURLConnection OkHttp3

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I've been struggling with this issue for quite some time, and I can't seem to find any answers online.

In my head, I'm closing everything that should be closed. I never get the response body, so I don't understand how it could be leaking, or how I should close it.

My code:

```
    try {
        String urlString = AppConfig.probeNodeReportHost();
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(json.toString());
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        conn.disconnect();
        return true;
    }catch(java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: Request timed out");
    }catch(java.net.UnknownHostException e){
        System.out.println("ERROR: Unknown host");
        if(AppConfig.hasNoInternetConnection()){
            System.out.println("NO INTERNET CONNECTION");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Has internet connection");
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Edit: The exact error message I'm getting is:

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to 'https://admin.ststage.se/' was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

Comment: would be helpfull to post any errors or warning you get.

Comment: which type of exception you are getting ? please share it

Comment: Late, but if it can help, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666053/okhttp-connection-leak-log-line-even-when-okhttp-is-not-a-dependency/62059933#62059933